# Visual Studio Code: How to see all classes inherited from a base class or interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Is there any way how I can see all classes inherited from a base class or an interface in Visual Studio Code? I know how to find all references, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for.

**NOTE**: This question relates to **Visual Studio Code**, not regular **Visual Studio**.

Comment: No, I do not think it is possible.

Comment: If it is particularly for your solution, try generating the class diagram.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is any other way than Find All References

Comment: find all... search for the class or interface across the entire solution... thats what i do... there is a very useful pay for add-on called resharper which can do this.

Comment: Right click the class name: Inspect - > Hierarchies CTRL E,H

Comment: An approach is to search the code for the inheritance notation, something like `extends BaseClass` or `implements BaseInterface`. Many languages (i.e. Typescript) support implementation of several interfaces in a class, so you would have to search for something like `implements.*BaseInterface` using the regular expression search mode. More other an interface may extend several interfaces. In this case we would need to search for `extends.*BaseInterface`.

Comment: Related C++ issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3799

Comment: Not sure for what language do you need it, but I found this proposal for Python: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18559 (if you need it, please upvote it)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it works for `C#` source code, but in general, you do it like this:

Right click the class name, and then choose *"Find All Implementations"*, or *"Peek>Peek Implementations"*.

OR

Place the cursor on a class name, press <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Windows, then start typing *"Implementations"*:

[image]